# How to remove nested fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, delete-row, updating

I have my index structure like, products:{data1: 1,data2:2}
How to remove only products.data1 from elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your doc with the script For Reading [Elasticsearch Doc Update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html)

**Example Code**

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/test/_doc/1/_update" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\u0027new_field\u0027)"
}'
```

I hope this will help to sort your problem.